# Ruby on Rails array not returning results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following were my query in controller:

```
@cref = Creference.where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "#{@city.downcase}")

  if @cref.present?
    cities_array = @cref.map {|con| "%#{con.countries}%" } 
    #cities_array return --> ["%["Kuching", "Kota Kinabalu"]%"]
    @products.where("city ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", cities_array) --> []
end
```

The `product` doesn't return any result despite there is city with above name in Product table. Thanks!!

SCHEMA

product:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "payment_type",        limit: 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                    precision: 6,             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                    precision: 6,             null: false
    t.integer  "product_category_id"
    t.integer  "location_id"
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "highlight"
    t.integer  "price_cents"
    t.integer  "zip"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "apt"
    t.integer  "refund_day"
    t.string   "currency"
    t.integer  "refund_percent"
    t.integer  "refundable",          limit: 2,               default: 0
    t.integer  "step",                limit: 2,               default: 0
    t.integer  "discount",                                    default: 0
    t.string   "slug"
    t.integer  "status",              limit: 2,               default: 1
    t.integer  "verification",        limit: 2,               default: 0
  end
```

creference:

```
  create_table "creferences", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "countries",  default: [],              array: true
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end
```

Comment: Maybe `@products` is empty or nil try `Product.where("city ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", cities_array) --> []` it should return products if matched any.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli why use Product.where?

Comment: It will search in whole table.

Comment: could you post the `schema` for **Creference** and **Product** model?

Comment: @Emu, check the schema updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
@cref = Creference.where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "#{@city.downcase}")

  if @cref.present?
    cities_array = @cref.collect {|con| con.countries }.flatten 
    #cities_array will return --> ["Kuching", "Kota Kinabalu"]
    @products.where("city IN (?)", cities_array) 
    # the IN query will find the city names that are in the cities_array
    # but in that case your product tables city name should be in lowercase
    # as you are fetching lowercase city names from Creference
end
```

**N.B.** I've not tested the code above. But it should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, check the value of `cities_array` to see what is returns.

Second, try to append `to_sql` at the end of the statement and to print it to see what the sql looks like:

```
puts @products.where("city ILIKE ANY ( array[?] )", cities_array).to_sql
```

Last but not least, `Product.count` to see that you actually have products in your table :).

Comment: This is the query i get `SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "products"."user_id" WHERE "products"."step" = 5 AND "products"."status" = 1 AND ("users"."merchant_status" = 1 OR "users"."merchant_status" = 0 AND "products"."verification" = 1) AND (city ILIKE ANY ( array['%["Kuching", "Kota Kinabalu"]%'] ))`

Comment: Is the last part valid SQL? I don't know which DBMS you use, but it looks weird to me. You can take this SQL statement and launch it on your dbms command line, so that you can see if you have a SQL or a Rails problem.

Comment: I am using postgres. And yet, it doesnt return anything

Comment: Then go to your `psql` CLI and try to launch the query above.

Comment: Which is good, you have a valid SQL query. It just does not do what you want...Try to refactor your AR query to make it do what you need (maybe check Emu's answer below).